# Could not find property 'xxxx' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I got this error after I added these lines to my gradle file:

```
buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey
    }
```

then the log show:

```
Could not find property 'MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@c3b784
```

The solutions on google that I searched cannot solve my problem. Please show me where I was wrong?

Comment: What is MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since you are using a `String` you have to use this syntax:

```
buildConfigField "String" , "OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY" ,  "\"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX\""
```

The last parameter has to be a String

Otherwise you can use something like this:

```
resValue "string", "OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY", "\"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX\""
```

The first case generates a constants iin your `BuildConfig` file.
The second case generates a string resource value that can be accessed using the `@string/OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY` annotation.

Answer (score 13):

You should define `MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey` in your *local user* settings, so, go to  your home gradle settings: `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` (Win: `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\gradle.properties`). If `gradle.properties` does not exist - just create it.

In the file add following line:

`MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`

(unfortunately, Android Udacity teachers were not very nice to explain how does it work from gradle perspective; as same as I've not easily found any documentation from gradle how *it.buildConfigField* works)

Comment: You're absolutely correct. This was taught very poorly (with a text node IIRC) and will be changed in the next iteration of the course. We'll actually be using your method here, as it is clearly the correct way of doing things. FWIW, one of the contributing factors to why this was taught poorly is because when the course was initially filmed, Open Weather Map did not require an API key, so a quick "bandaid" fix was required to keep everything from breaking. Anyway, please feel free to shoot me an email at halfjew22 at gmail.com and we can chat about the best way to show these concepts. Cheers!

Comment: @radistao I have added that but it says `Error:(21, 0) Could not find property 'MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey' on       
com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@12b151b.`

Comment: @SiddharthVenu It worked for me when adding `MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey = "API_KEY_HERE"` to the gradle.properties file in the Sunshine-Version-2 directory.

Comment: @VishnuM. same here, but the instructions says to create anther `gradle.properties` in the `.gradle` folder in the project directory. They tell you have to do that because the `gradle.properties` in the project dir will be included in the Git and others can see out key.

Comment: FYI - I had to read here to figure out how to get this to work. There was no mention, that I recall, in the Udacity course. Lots of other similar challenges in the course.

Answer (score 11):

The 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY' references a gradle property named 'MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey' that needs to be configured.

One reason is for the build system to generate the code for this. Another might be so that you don't accidentally commit your API-KEY to GitHub or other public repo.

What you should do is add an entry to your 'gradle.properties' file like this:

MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey="[YOUR-API-KEY]"

Then sync your project with gradle (if using Android Studio)

Answer (score 5):

See " Open Weather Map API Key is required." at the bottom of https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2

Answer (score 4):

1. Sign up account at http://openweathermap.org/appid#use or other weather api providers to get your unique API Key
2. Go to your home gradle settings: ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Add this line:

```
MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey="yourUniqueApiKey"
```

3. Rebuild it

Answer (score 2):

I had to use a little information from multiple answers on here to fix this issue.

1. `it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey` is fine. The top voted answer puts the key directly into this field rather than referencing a "global" key for your user.
2. You need to acquire a Open Weather Map API Key by making an account [here](http://www.openweathermap.org/appid)
3. Gradle expects you to put the key that you get from creating an Open Weather Map account into a field named `MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey` that is referenced by `OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY` from before. To do this, open gradle.properties in Android Studio and add `MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey="<Your Key Here>"`

Now you should be able to build the app with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is absolutely correct. Another way, probably simpler, to format the value inside as the String is like this:

```
it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', '"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"'
```