# AndroidStudio build.gradle not recognizing a variable in gradle.properties

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I created a file `gradle.properties` in `.gradle` folder, and added a variable:

```
MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey=”b86b2******a2cc***a5fa***ae14c30”
```

(Some letters starred for security)

And here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.sunshine.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

It says

```
Error:(21, 0) Could not find property 'MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey' on       
com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@12b151b.`
```

Why isn't the variable from `gradle.properties` recognized?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226978/could-not-find-property-xxxx-on-com-android-build-gradle-appextension-decorate

Comment: @user35603 sir, I want to use the variable specified in the `gradle.properties`. The answers tells me to directly input the string instead of using variables.

Comment: It seem the file gradle.properties should be already there. If you are using Android Studio it should be at the bottom after "gradle" and before "External libraries". It should not be in ".gradle".

Comment: @user35603 thank you so much! Pls post as answer. ill acpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem the file `gradle.properties` should be already there. If you are using `Android Studio` it should be at the bottom after `gradle` folder and before `External libraries`. It shouldn't be in `.gradle`.