# Error when building - Could not find property 'MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey'

Tags: java, android, gradle

i got this error from gradle when i try to build the project after i put the api key in gradle file

```
android {
.....
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'cedf6......80c62', MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey
    }
}
```

this error i got when i build the project :-

```
    Error:(22, 0) Could not find property 'MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@48bee3b8.
<a href="openFile:F:\Projects\Android\advanced sunshine\Advanced_Android_Development\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

i think i have to make a file in some folder , but i don't know in which folder ? , 
and what i ishould to type inside the file after i create it  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a `String` you have to use this syntax:

`buildConfigField "String" , "OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY" ,  "\"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX\""`
The last parameter has to be a String

Otherwise you can use something like this:

`resValue "string", "OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY", "\"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX\""`
The first case generates a constants iin your BuildConfig file.
The second case generates a string resource value that can be accessed using the `@string/OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY` annotation.

Credits: [Could not find property 'xxxx' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226978/could-not-find-property-xxxx-on-com-android-build-gradle-appextension-decorate)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a combination of double quotes and single quotes to avoid the escape characters *(where xxx is your API)*:

```
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', '"xxxxxxxxx"'
}
```